# Lightswitch with WCF RIA Services datasource - Query operation [operation name] could not be found on the service

Tags: wcf-ria-services, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have built out my Lightswitch app to use a WCF RIA Services data source.  I was able to reference my RIA Service project, and import the data types. However, any call to the service results in a "Query operation [operationname] could not be found on the service".

The real scary thing is that I have not found a hit in the search engines for this error - so I must be doing something VERY wrong.

The method signature looks like this:

```
public IQueryable<md_SKURevMngtRRPPhantom> GetRRPPhantoms(string site, string category, long? segment, DateTime? entryDate){
//implementation here
}
```

I have used Fiddler to see the call being made to the service...it looks like this:

```
http://localhost:26132/RevMngtDomainServiceData.svc/GetRRPPhantoms()?site='610'&category='B'&segment=5L&entryDate=datetime'2013-07-04T00:00:00'
```

Even a parameterless request to the default service method returns the same error.
This default request is defined as follows:

```
[Query(IsDefault = true)]
public IQueryable<md_SKURevMngtRRPPhantom> GetAllRRPPhantoms(){
///implementation here...
}
```

How can my Lightswitch project correctly import the WCF RIA Service as a datasource, and yet calls to the same service return "Query operation [operation name] could not be found on the service."?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I was indeed doing something very wrong...the md_SKURevMngtRRPPhantom object that I was returning, was an object defined in the Lightswitch project's DataSource that I was adding a property to by creating a partial class of it in my DomainService project.  Seems this was a bad idea.

I changed the DomainService project to return a newly-defined class instead of a the md_SKURevMngtRRPPhantom class, and all worked fine.